# Implementing Wilson Score Interval;

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implementing the wilson score interval as seen here:
http://www.goproblems.com/test/wilson/wilson-new.php?v1=0&v2=0&v3=0&v4=0&v5=2

PHP Source: http://www.goproblems.com/test/wilson/wilson-new.php.txt

However, I cannot seem to get the same numbers as in the php example.

> Where the second 2 is the total ratings
>
> Where the first 2 is the sum rating for a rating of 5 which I get by:

`double sum = ((5 - 1) / 4.0) * Total_5_star_Ratings`

2 Ratings which are both 5 stars:

```
Console.WriteLine(5 * ci_lower_bound(2, 2));

        public static double ci_lower_bound(double sum, int n)
        {
            if (n == 0)
                return 0.0;
            double z = 1.96;
            const int k = 4;
            double ave = sum/n;

            return ((ave + ((z * z) / (2 * n))) - z * Math.Sqrt((k * ave * (1 - ave) + (z * z) / (4 * n)) / n)) / (1 + (k * (z * z)) / n);
        }
```

Comment: I got the same problem with them... I've just test it I got 1,734.. they got to have an error somewhere

Comment: for n=1 and x bar=2 and z=1,96 I've got 1,734

Answer (score 0):

I found the error you may have since you don't post the result you have.

instead of

```
double sum = ((5 - 1) / 4.0) * Total_5_star_Ratings
```

you should get in your case

```
double ave = (5 * n)/n
```

and then
    double xbar = (ave - 1)/4

and in your formula

```
double result = (( ave + ((z * z) / (2 * n))) - z * Math.Sqrt((((ave * (1 - ave) + (z * z) / (4 * n)) / n)) / (1 + (z * z / n)));
return result 1 + 4 * result;
```

I did not test it but this should get you on track. check the parenthesis